# Set theory and rational numbers

Tags: rational-numbers

A set $Q$ contains $0$, $1$ and the average of all elements of every finite non-empty subset of $Q$. Prove that $Q$ contains all rational numbers in $[0,1]$.

This is the exact wording, as it was given to me. 
Obviously, the elements that correspond to the average, are rational, since they can be expressed as $\frac{(q_1+q_2+\dots q_k)}{k}$, where $0\leq k\leq1$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @5xum thanks for the edit! I am new here and not very familiar with the editor!

Comment: Just a quick comment - I would change your subscript on the $q_k$ to avoid using $k$ with two different meanings :-)

Comment: You shouldn't have $0\leq k\leq 1$, it's the $q$'s that are between $0$ and $1$, not the index.

Answer (score 4):

Let's explore the first few possibilities to see what's going on.

- You already know that $Q$ contains $0$ and $1$.
- The average of $0$ and $1$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, so this is in $Q$ too.
- The average of $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ and the average of $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ is $\frac{3}{4}$.
- For $\frac{1}{3}$, we see that this is the average of $0$, $\frac{1}{4}$, and $\frac{3}{4}$.  Similarly, $\frac{2}{3}$ is the average of $1$, $\frac{3}{4}$, and $\frac{1}{4}$.

Now, let's prove this more completely (although somewhat sketchy because the complete rigor is somewhat messy).

Step 1: Prove that all dyadic numbers are in this set.  A dyadic number is a fraction of the form $\frac{a}{2^n}$ for integer $a$ and some natural number $n$.  For our case, it is safe to assume that $a$ is odd and that $0<a<2^n$.

Proof by induction on $n$, the only dyadic number (satisfying the conditions) when $n=1$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, which is the average of $0$ and $1$.

Inductive step, consider the dyadic number $\frac{a}{2^{n+1}}$.  We can observe that this is the average of $\frac{a+1}{2^{n+1}}$ and $\frac{a-1}{2^{n+1}}$.  Note that both $a+1$ and $a-1$ are even, so these are actually dyadic numbers with smaller denominators, so they are in the set by the inductive hypothesis (if $a+1=2^{n+1}$ or $a-1=0$, then these numbers are $0$ or $1$, which are given to be in the set).

Step 2: Prove that all rational numbers are in the set using dyadic numbers.

Let $\frac{p}{q}$ be an arbitrary rational number.  To get this rational number, it must be an average of $q$ numbers whose sum is $p$.  We can write $p$ as a sum of dyadic numbers in the following way:

Choose $p$ dyadic numbers that are all near $1$, for example, $\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$.  With various $n$'s large enough, the difference between the sum of these numbers and $p$ is a small (close to zero) dyadic number.  It would be of the form $\frac{a}{2^n}$ for $a$ relatively small.

We now need to write $\frac{a}{2^n}$ as a sum of $q-p$ dyadic numbers.  We can rewrite this fraction as $\frac{a2^m}{2^{n+m}}$ so that $a2^m$ is larger than $q-p$, let this be $\frac{b}{2^{n+m}}$, observe that this is the sum of $\frac{b-1}{2^{n+m+1}}$ and $\frac{b+1}{2^{n+m+1}}$.  By repeatedly splitting the smallest element of the set in this way until you have $q-p$ elements, you have a collection whose average is $\frac{p}{q}$.  Note that by the choice of $b$, you'll never reach $0$ using this splitting technique (and that all of the numbers are distinct).

Comment: you are a genius!

Comment: You might want to try alternate constructions for $\frac{p}{q}$, different approaches might give an expression that's easier to write down.

Answer (score 0):

By successively taking midpoints we can produce all numbers of the form
$${k\over2^n}\qquad(n\geq0, \ 0\leq k\leq 2^n)\ .$$
Now let two numbers $0<p<q$ be given. Write $q-p=:p'$ for simplicity. Choose a sufficiently large $n$ (see below), and put
$$k_i:=i-1\quad(0< i\leq p'),\qquad k_{q-i}:=2^n-i\quad(0\leq i<p)\ .$$
One then has
$$\sum_{i=1}^q k_i=p\cdot 2^n+{(p'-1)p'\over2}-{(p-1)p\over2}=:p\cdot 2^n+\Delta\ .$$
Note that $|\Delta|<{q^2\over2}$. If $\Delta>0$ replace the *first* "large" $k_i\,$, namely $k_{p'+1}$, by $\ k_{p'+1}^{\rm new}:=k_{p'+1}-\Delta$. If $n$ is large enough then one still has $k_{p'+1}^{\rm new}>k_{p'}$. Make a similar correction if $\Delta<0$. The numbers
$$x_i:={k_i\over 2^n}\in Q\quad(1\leq i\leq q)$$
 now form an  increasing sequence of $q$ *different* numbers, and one has
$${1\over q}\sum_{i=1}^q x_i={1\over q\cdot 2^n}\sum_{i=1}^q k_i={p\cdot 2^n\over q\cdot 2^n}={p\over q}\ ,$$
hence ${p\over q}\in Q$.